# Elementary Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I wish to prove the following:

If $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function, $x_0$ is a point in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(x_0) = 0$, and $f''(x_0) > 0$ (so in particular $f''$ exists at $x_0$), then there is a $d > 0$ so that $f(x_0) < f(x)$ for all $x \in (x_0 - d, x_0 + d)$ that aren't equal to $x_0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the **definition** of the derivative. If the limit as $h$ approaches $0$ of $\dfrac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$ is positive, then  $f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)$ is positive for all (non-zero) $h$ that are close  enough to $0$.  The notation of your question is a bit different, but this is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that for any $d$ and for any $x$ such that $x\in (x_0-d,x_0+d)$ implies $f(x_0)\geq f(x)$. Then $f$ is concave down at $x_0$ so the second derivative is negative which is a contradiction.